# Custom taxonomy not echoing url properly

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a URL structure that follow this structure:

/products/(product_category)/(post-name)/

(product_category) is a custom taxonomy.

Each product category only has a few products, and each product only has 1 category. I use the following to produce a link to category page that shows the products under that category:

PHP:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    $image     = get_field('product_categories_image', $term );
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
```

HTML:

```
<a class="product-individual" href="<?php echo $term_link ?>" title="<?php echo $term->name ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
```

When using the browser inspector, I can see that the "title" tag properly displays, but not the URL. This is what is produced:

Output:

```
http://"siteurl"/?taxonomy=product_category&term=hotelgift-cards-holders
```

Comment: Make sure that you have rebuild your permalinks.

Comment: https://www.icegreen.ca/new/products/%product_category%/%postname% is what the permalink is, and i've cleared the cache and whatnot.

Comment: Seems your code works fine for me. check $terms return array properly?

Comment: update the permalinks in settings and check

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: Update the permalinks structure, then get the code in your .htaccess, and put it up here. That may help people who know how it should look like. :)

Comment: This all that appears in the htaccess file

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Actually, I no longer have the same issue. Should I post a new question? -- I have the proper permalink stucture --> /products/thermal-bags/insulated-lunch-bags/

Except that the single-products.php file is no longer being referenced. This picture shows the args used to create the post-type named "products". http://imgur.com/dKMaYHx